# Llamar a un objeto con LinkedList.get()

Tags: java, poo, lista, clase, objeto

soy nuevo con esto de java y quiciera saber como puedo acceder a los atributos de un objeto de una clase que se encuentra dentro de una lista creada utilizando la libreria linkedList() que proporciona java. Dado que cuando llamo al elemento de la lista solo se muestra el nombre de la clase y la dirección del objeto.

A continuación muestro el codigo donde creo la lista "lista_de_LinkedList", cuando añado un nuevo elemento con el constructor de la clase Estudiante y cuando pretendo mostrar el elemento.

```
    Estudiante claseEstudiante;
    //Declaracion de una nueva lista de la libreria linkedList()
    LinkedList lista_de_LinkedList = new LinkedList();

    //Llenar lista1 con 3 nuevos estudiantes
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {   
        nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Lista enlazada simple mediante libreria LinkedList\n\n"
                + "Ingrese el nombre del Estudiante a Agregar:");
        edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la edad del estudiante:"));
        codigo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el codigo del estudiante:"));
        //Aqui se llama al metodo add de la libreria LinkedList para agregar los tres estudiantes
        //a la lista lista_de_LinkedList
        lista_de_LinkedList.add(claseEstudiante = new Estudiante(nombre, codigo, edad)); 
    }

    //Ahora se procede a mostrar la nueva lista creada usando los metodos .size() para obtener la cantidad
    //de nodos de la lista y .get() para obtener el dato de un nodo
    System.out.println("Esta nueva lista tiene " + lista_de_LinkedList.size() + " elementos:");
    for (int i = 0; i < lista_de_LinkedList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("   Elemnto Numero " + (i+1) + ": " + lista_de_LinkedList.get(i));
    }
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: `LinkedList` no es una biblioteca, sino una clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque no has especificado al crear la lista, de qué tipo de elementos va a ser esa lista. Para hacer eso, indicas la clase de objetos que contendrá en la definición:

```
LinkedList<Estudiante> lista_de_LinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Con esto estás indicando que van a ser objetos de la clase `Estudiante`.

Cuando añades elementos en la lista, estás haciendo algo redundante que es usar una variable. Puedes crear el objeto directamente y lo que te retorne `new` se guardará en la lista:

```
lista_de_LinkedList.add( new Estudiante(nombre, codigo, edad));
```

La variable `claseEstudiante` no te hace falta para nada. Se crea un objeto `Estudiante`, y se añade en la lista.

Y para extraer, dado que ya has especificado de qué clase son los objetos que se van a guardar, la función `get` te va a devolver un objeto `Estudiante` y podrás directamente ejecutar sobre él los métodos que tenga, o acceder a las variables públicas que tenga.

```
Estudiante unEstudiante = lista_de_LinkedList.get( posicion);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya funciona el programa con tu expllicación.

Comment: La razón del porque no le funciona el código al OP es porque le faltó hacer un "casteo" para poder usar los miembros de la clase `Estudiante`. Ejemplo: `((Estudiante)lista_de_LinkedList.get(i)).getNombre()`